# MATLAB How to use annotation text box with latex?

Tags: matlab, textbox, annotations, latex

I try to use the an annotation textbox in MATLAB with latex style. I use this code for the text inside the textbox.

```
textp={'Einstellungen:',...                     
['w = ',num2str(w),' m/s'],...                  %Display w
['u = ',num2str(u),' m/s'],...                  %Display u
['r_p = ',num2str(r_p*10^6),' µm'],...          %Display Radius 
['beta = ',num2str(beta),'°']};                 %Display beta
```

Then I call annotation with this code:

```
annotation(Flugbahn,'textbox',dim,...     
'String',textp,...                              
'Interpreter','latex',...
```

The Problem is there is always the warning

```
String must have valid interpreter syntax:
```

Even if I use `$\mu$m` is there a warning and the text inside the texbox is not in latex sytle.

Answer (score 1):

After long searching I found the solution:

```
textp={'Einstellungen:',...
['w= ' num2str(w) ' m/s'],...
['u= ' num2str(u) ' m/s'],...
['r= ' num2str(r_p*10^6) ' $\mu$m' ],...
['$\alpha$= ' num2str(alpha) '$^\circ$'],...
['$\beta$= ' num2str(beta) '$^\circ$']};
```

The Problem was `r_p`. That was the reason the annotation always change back to Tex. Now everything is in LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by `TeX` and `LaTeX` interpreters that Matlab uses. The `LaTeX` interpreter suppress plain `TeX` commands and demand `LaTeX` commands. And `TeX` iterpreter works above the plain TeX allowing, for example, wider use of fonts etc. That's why TeX and LaTeX cannot digest `\mum` sequence but `TeX` interpreter can. It changes it to `$\mu$m` sequence and passes it to actual TeX.

If you rely on `LaTeX` interpreter use LaTeX commands, not TeX commands.

The proper text is

- `'\(\mu m\)'` to obtain italic mu and regular m;
- `'\(\mu m\)'` to obtain italic mu and italic m.

Note that `math` mode `\(\)` switches to italics.

If you do not rely on `LaTeX` you can use Matlab's (default) iterpretation of TeX.

- `'\mum'` to obtain regular mu and regular m;
- `'{\it\mum}'` to obtain italic mu and italic m;
- `'{\it\mu}m'` to obtaion italic mu and regular m;
- `'\mu\itm'` to obtain regular mu and italic m and everything behind it;
- `'\mu{\itm}'` to obtain regular mu and italic m.

Note that `TeX` interpreter ignores math mode shape changes and expands TeX shape commands to both text and math modes following the shaping command.

I also recommend using:

- `5\cdot10^6` instead of `5*10^6`;
- `5 \circC` instead of `5 °C`;
- `LaTeX` interpreter for images that will be used in LaTeX-looking documents with Computer Modern fonts;
- `TeX` interpreter for other documents (there is no need of Computer Modern font).

---

Inspired by R.Ugolini's answer:

```
textp={'Einstellungen:',...                     
['\(w\) = ',num2str(w),' m/s'],...                  %Display w
['\(u\) = ',num2str(u),' m/s'],...                  %Display u
['\(r_\mathrm p\) = ',num2str(r_p*10^6),' \(\mu\)m'],...          %Display Radius 
['\(\beta\) = ',num2str(beta),'\(^\circ\)']};                 %Display beta
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I need LaTeX because I write my bachelor thesis in LaTeX . Everything else works with LaTeX. I can even use the command '$\mu$m' in x or y labels and it works.  Your solution with ''\(\mu m\)'' doesn't work. It's strange maybe it's because i use '{}' but I need that for the columns

Comment: Try to use primitive command `text(x,y,textp,'parent',ax,'interpreter','latex')` where `x` and `y` are coordinates in the axes `ax` you want to place it in. I have no experience with `annotation` so far...

Answer (score -1):

No dollar sign is needed. Simply use '\mum'. Besides, use char(176) for the degree sign.

Comment: `'\mum'` string for writing microns works when interpreter is TeX - default Matlab interpreter. When interpreter is switched to LaTeX it tries to evaluate command `\mum` which does not exist.